# Assistance needed with formatting Y-axis ticks on a d3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, yaxis

I'm struggling with a c3.js chart, more specifically the y-axis. The values are formatted '00,50,00,50' and not corresponding with my data. The 0 is always not at the very bottom. I've embedded a picture of the chart and the code I'm using if anyone can let me know what's missing I'd be grateful. 
[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAySQ.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart2',
        size: {
          height: 450,
          width: 1020
        },
        padding: {
                  top: 10,
                  right: 40,
                  bottom: 10,
                  left: 20
              },
              bar: {
                      width: 35
                  },

      data: {
          x: 'x',
          xFormat: '%H:%M',
          columns: [

              ['x', "17:25","17:26","17:27","17:28","17:29","17:30",
              "17:31","17:32","17:33","17:34","17:35","17:36","17:37",
              "17:38","17:39","17:40","17:41","17:42","17:43","17:44",
              "17:45","17:46","17:47","17:48","17:49","17:50","17:51",
              "17:52","17:53","17:54","17:55","17:56","17:57","17:58",
              "17:59","18:00","18:01","18:02","18:03","18:04","18:05",
              "18:06","18:07","18:08","18:09","18:10","18:11","18:12",
              "18:13","18:14","18:15","18:16","18:17","18:18","18:19",
              "18:20","18:21","18:22","18:23","18:24","18:25","18:26",
              "18:27","18:28","18:29","18:30","18:31","18:32","18:33",
              "18:34","18:35","18:36","18:37","18:38","18:39","18:40",
              "18:41","18:42","18:43","18:44","18:45","18:46","18:47",
              "18:48","18:49","18:50","18:51","18:52","18:53","18:54",
              "18:55","18:56","18:57","18:58","18:59","19:00","19:01",
              "19:02","19:03","19:04","19:05","19:06","19:07","19:08",
              "19:09","19:10","19:11","19:12","19:13","19:14","19:15",
              "19:16","19:17","19:18","19:19","19:20","19:21","19:22",
              "19:23","19:24","19:25","19:26","19:27","19:28","19:29",
              "19:30","19:31","19:32","19:33","19:34","19:35","19:36",
              "19:37","19:38","19:39","19:40","19:41","19:42","19:43",
              "19:44","19:45","19:46","19:47","19:48","19:49","19:50",
              "19:51","19:52","19:53","19:54","19:55","19:56","19:57",
              "19:58","19:59","20:00","20:01","20:02","20:03","20:04",
              "20:05","20:06","20:07","20:08","20:09","20:10","20:11",
              "20:12","20:13","20:14","20:15","20:16","20:17","20:18",
              "20:19","20:20","20:21","20:22","20:23","20:24","20:25",
              "20:26","20:27","20:28","20:29","20:30","20:31","20:32",
              "20:33","20:34","20:35","20:36","20:37","20:38","20:39",
              "20:40","20:41","20:42","20:43","20:44","20:45","20:46",
              "20:47","20:48","20:49","20:50","20:51","20:52","20:53",
              "20:54","20:55","20:56","20:57","20:58","20:59","21:00",
              "21:01","21:02","21:03","21:04","21:05","21:06","21:07",
              "21:08","21:09","21:10","21:11","21:12","21:13","21:14",
              "21:15","21:16","21:17","21:18","21:19","21:20","21:21",
              "21:22","21:23","21:24","21:25","21:26","21:27","21:28",
              "21:29","21:30","21:31","21:32","21:33","21:34","21:35",
              "21:36","21:37"],
              ['Tweets', 7,8,6,3,9,11,4,9,4,6,9,8,8,3,5,6,4,12,5,6,9,
              14,13,11,9,11,7,16,7,7,6,3,4,4,9,23,14,2,8,8,4,6,9,6,7,
              7,6,7,10,9,8,8,7,11,12,7,6,14,5,17,8,9,5,7,6,9,6,6,9,8,
              10,9,7,7,8,6,5,5,2,8,8,7,9,12,17,3,11,2,6,5,2,2,6,5,10,
              28,19,24,24,54,62,74,82,63,65,74,88,105,87,108,66,54,41,
              59,78,51,49,75,58,49,61,52,59,79,71,67,61,57,68,42,76,
              78,88,84,102,77,52,67,114,115,113,97,159,177,136,85,58,
              91,72,64,87,105,102,69,91,97,77,60,48,165,254,199,132,
              149,113,76,71,77,62,72,68,94,98,120,93,80,105,90,82,55,
              74,85,65,72,64,79,70,75,79,126,96,81,82,83,85,72,46,86,
              64,63,67,54,87,121,81,87,95,71,51,56,57,34,76,69,120,118,
              79,74,69,61,42,61,128,338,304,253,198,219,217,179,128,118,
              91,79,79,63,66,56,54,47,47,51,39,42,41,47,49,33,49,41,
              25,28,4],
              ['Retweets', 13,19,27,26,23,16,23,24,22,21,15,14,22,18,19,
              12,17,19,18,24,25,20,16,16,17,16,23,20,13,24,22,10,19,23,9,
              9,20,22,14,13,22,16,23,16,16,16,13,14,14,18,21,9,14,18,14,17,
              13,16,15,15,21,20,24,11,14,15,19,22,14,20,11,15,14,11,9,12,21,
              12,16,13,19,13,19,17,8,24,16,23,11,24,20,21,18,30,27,18,19,24,
              33,18,29,31,30,18,22,24,32,27,21,30,23,36,34,24,31,32,39,34,28,
              21,14,20,37,32,33,30,28,33,33,29,36,36,38,39,28,37,37,29,31,50,
              36,30,41,43,51,51,39,33,36,26,21,29,34,64,36,45,46,35,17,34,71,
              74,73,63,77,73,48,54,56,30,30,45,63,55,42,40,26,41,51,46,47,52,
              36,41,43,43,44,33,28,35,52,53,33,48,49,36,64,47,45,44,31,41,33,
              41,39,37,33,52,47,38,49,24,21,24,27,40,77,51,51,52,49,53,86,238,
              205,202,187,231,198,176,149,124,115,120,95,93,105,99,87,103,63,
              68,79,78,99,80,68,74,62,80,85,62,17],
              ['Replies', 1,4,4,4,0,1,4,3,4,6,2,11,2,4,3,8,4,8,4,3,3,1,2,3,2,
              4,9,6,2,2,7,2,2,4,18,4,4,2,2,0,3,3,1,5,4,5,1,3,2,2,3,4,7,4,5,3,
              5,4,3,9,11,11,16,2,6,9,2,3,1,8,2,3,2,7,2,1,9,2,11,4,22,7,22,3,6,
              11,3,13,4,9,19,18,17,23,2,3,4,3,5,9,7,8,8,3,15,2,4,5,12,9,8,8,14,
              6,8,9,12,8,8,13,12,4,5,4,7,6,12,7,9,9,8,8,9,8,12,9,15,16,19,28,23,
              28,9,17,17,24,19,14,21,23,4,13,9,9,6,5,15,11,7,8,12,19,18,24,16,21,
              19,14,13,11,15,12,12,12,17,8,18,15,18,15,14,15,12,18,9,13,11,12,12,
              7,21,14,14,13,9,11,54,12,15,22,14,22,23,15,16,24,25,13,15,14,16,10,
              12,7,15,13,17,9,10,20,10,9,9,13,12,22,21,21,19,21,21,16,20,16,19,17,
              14,14,19,16,20,18,13,12,10,12,11,12,14,11,14,10,3]

          ]
      },
      axis: {
          x: {
              type: 'timeseries',
              // if true, treat x value as localtime (Default)
              // if false, convert to UTC internally
              localtime: false,
              tick: {
                  format: '%H:%M',
              }
          }
      });
```

Comment: I think the y axis scale is being clipped, so the numbers are 0, 50, 100, 150, 200 etc, but the 100's are not visible, so it looks like 0, 50, 00, 50, 00, 50. If you adjust the margins it should bring it on the chart